# Dúvida ao criar structs, relacionando uma struct a outra

Tags: c

Eu criei as seguintes structs:

```
typedef struct cliente{
    unsigned long int codigo;
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[50];
    char cpf[11];
    char idade[3];
    struct cliente* prox;
}Cliente;

typedef struct funcionario{
    unsigned int codigo;
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[50];
    struct funcionario* prox;
}Funcionario;

typedef struct veiculo {
    unsigned int codigo;
    char placa[6];
    char modelo[50];
    char cor[30];
    char assentos[2];
    struct veiculo* prox;
}Veiculo;
```

Elas tem a função de armazenar dados e cadastrar algumas informações sobre **cliente**, **veículo** e **funcionário**, dessa forma: (os demais tem a mesma estrutura):

```
//Inserindo clientes
Cliente* inserir_cliente(Cliente *primeiroCliente){
    Cliente cliente;
    Cliente *atual = primeiroCliente;
    char identificador = 'F' ;

    //Lendo as informacoes do cliente.
    printf(" Codigo do cliente: ");
    scanf("%u", &cliente.codigo); printf("\n");
    printf(" Nome: ");
    fflush(stdin); fgets(cliente.nome, 40, stdin); printf("\n");
    printf(" Endere%co: ", 135);
    fflush(stdin); fgets(cliente.endereco, 40, stdin); printf("\n");
    printf(" CPF: ");
    fflush(stdin); fgets(cliente.cpf, 11, stdin); printf("\n");
    printf(" Idade: ");
    fflush(stdin); fgets(cliente.idade, 11, stdin); printf("\n");

    //Verificando se o cadastro ja existe.
    for(atual=primeiroCliente; atual!=NULL; atual=atual->prox){
        if(atual->codigo==cliente.codigo){
            identificador = 'V';
            break;
        }
    }

    if(identificador!='V' && (strlen(cliente.nome)!=1 && strlen(cliente.endereco)!=1)){
        //Alocando espacos e guardando informacoes do cliente.
        Cliente* NovoCliente=(Cliente*) malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
        strcpy(NovoCliente->nome, cliente.nome);
        strcpy(NovoCliente->endereco, cliente.endereco);
        strcpy(NovoCliente->cpf, cliente.cpf);
        strcpy(NovoCliente->idade, cliente.idade);
        NovoCliente->codigo = cliente.codigo;
        NovoCliente->prox = primeiroCliente;
        printf(" Cadastro realizado com sucesso.");
        printf("\n\n PRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA PARAVA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL.");
        return NovoCliente;
    }else{
        printf(" Cadastro inv%clido.", 160);
        printf(" \n\n PRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA PARA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL.");
        return primeiroCliente;
    }

}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu também fiz a seguinte estrutura:

```
typedef struct locacao {
    unsigned long int codigo;
    int cod_veiculo;
    char modelo[50];
    char cor[30];
    int codCliente;
    char nomeCliente[50];
    char idadeCliente[2];
    int codFuncionario;
    char nomeFuncionario[50];
    Data locacao;
    struct locacao* prox;
}Locacao;
```

Eu gostaria de saber se teria alguma forma de eu inserir informações na struct **Locacao** a partir dos dados já cadastrados nas struct, **cliente**, **funcionario** e **veiculo**.

Obs: Estou fazendo no DevC++, no ambiente windows.

Quem quiser verificar o código inteiro:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q5Bl5Tf0F0sIiz_lWFmtn0DKS-whZ1NZ

Comment: Apenas numa ótica de ajudar nesta e em futuras questões, a tag DevC++ que colocou não se aplica nesta pergunta, nem em nenhuma das que fez para trás pois não tem influência no código em si. Apenas faria sentido colocar se estivesse a utilizar alguma funcionalidade especifica do editor. Pode no entanto indicar como observação, assim como fez, para dar mais contexto a quem lê a pergunta, se achar que é relevante.

Comment: Em que parte da `struct locacao` viria o cliente por exemplo ? No `int codCliente;` ?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sugestão. Isso mesmo eu gostaria que ao inserir o `int codCliente` o sistema faça uma busca na `struct cliente` e retorne `char nomeCliente[50]`, e o `char IdadeCliente[2]`.

Comment: Fazer uma busca com base no `id` é diferente de cada `locacao` ter um ponteiro para o cliente correspondente, sendo que a segunda opção regra geral é preferível, pois reduz a redundância.